# How to include a table within an email

Tags: java, email

I want an email to be sent automatically. I am implementing this thing with the help of struts framework. I need to send an email where there will be an URL of a particular portal and the email body should contain a table with two columns but the number of rows is not fixed.

Comment: Same as you do in HTML

Comment: Send it as html? How to do it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java

Comment: Can you please tell us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far, besides asking us?

Comment: In JavaMail I've cheated by creating the Mail in the User-Client (Thunderbird), looking at the source code and transfering it in my project. Maybe it's a solution fitting for you, too. Cheers!

Comment: can you upload your code?

Comment: I have cast a delete vote on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your email can be an HTML email. So you'd use HTML to implement the table, and set the email mime type headers accordingly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1666484/1372207) tells you how to set the mime type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

first create your `table` as in String format then set that String in `setMsg()`

```
 MultiPartEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();

        email.setSmtpPort(getPortNumber());
        // authenticating the user
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(getSenderID(),
                getSenderPassword()));
        // email.setDebug(true);
        email.setSSL(true);
        //
        email.setTLS(true);
        // setting the host name
        email.setHostName(getHostName());
        // setting the rciever id

        email.addTo(receiverId);
        email.setFrom(getSenderID());
            // setting the subject of mail
        email.setSubject(getSubject());
        email.setMsg("<table border="1"><tr><td></td></tr>");//here is your html code
        email.send();
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response.I have used a while loop in my action class method and included that table inside that while loop.The table I created is simple html code inside the message body.